# Why asp.net core logging everything?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, logging, serilog

I have creted my first asp.net core 3.0 application. And setup.cs file with serilog file extension  like following:

```
   public class Startup
    {
        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddControllers();
        }
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }

            loggerFactory.AddFile("logs/ts-{Date}.txt");
            ....
```

And appsettings.json is:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

But this logs so many information while application running. But I want to save only my log calls in controller actions or anywhere else:

```
 public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
 {
    private readonly ILogger<WeatherForecastController> _logger;

    public WeatherForecastController(ILogger<WeatherForecastController> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
       _logger.LogInformation("oops");
       ....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The default template for .NET Core 3 projects also has a `appsettings.Development.json` file which overrides settings in the base `appsettings.json` file. It will look something like this:

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  }
}
```

Note that the log level is set to `Debug` which is why your logs contain so many entries.

From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-3.0#json-configuration-provider):

> `AddJsonFile` is automatically called twice when you initialize a new host builder with `CreateDefaultBuilder`. The method is called to load configuration from:
>
> - *appsettings.json* – This file is read first. The environment version of the file can override the values provided by the appsettings.json file.
> - *appsettings.{Environment}.json* – The environment version of the file is loaded based on the IHostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName.

Answer (score 0):

as @DavidG already answered, the logging levels specify the logs that are logged.

check the out this below links for more information on logging:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging-1

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#log-level-1

below is a sample that logs only the `_logger.LogInformation("oops");`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "None",
      "System": "None"
    }
  }
}
```